# Java swing - frequently changing color of the frame

Tags: java, swing, colors, timer, background

I'm facing the problem with changing the color of the frame. I created timer timer1 and initially set the color of the frame to co1_ for instance (RED). 
Now, when I tried to compare actual color with predefined values I'm always getting the message:

> Frame color is: javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=238,g=238,b=238]

and the frame color is still remaining red. Do you have any clue what I'm doing wrong? :)

Thanks in advance.

```
    Color col1 = Color.RED;
    Color col1_= new Color(255,0,0);
    Color col2 = Color.GREEN;
    Color col2_ = new Color(238,238,238);

    JFrame jfrmForm = new JFrame();
    jfrmForm.setSize(400, 300);
    jfrmForm.setLocation(300,300); 
    jfrmForm.setVisible(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
    jfrmForm.getContentPane().setBackground(col1_);                      

    //getting color from Frame
    Color c = getContentPane().getBackground();       

    timer.start(); 
    timer.setRepeats(false);

    Timer timer1 = new Timer(1000*frekvCmbBox, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (c.equals(col1_)) {
                jfrmForm.getContentPane().setBackground(col2_);
                System.out.println("Frame color is_: " + c.toString());
            }
            else {
                jfrmForm.getContentPane().setBackground(col1_);
                System.out.println("Frame color is: " + c.toString());
            }                 
        }
    });

    timer1.start();
```

Comment: BTW - move `Color c = getContentPane().getBackground();` **inside** the action performed method!

Answer (score 1):

Andrew, thanks for help - it works now!

```
Moving Color c = getContentPane().getBackground();
```

to the inside of the action performed method was the key. 
And, I'm sorry for answering - it seems that I didn't read forum rules carefully.

Comment: Now I actually realized that I made very stupid mistake - I was getting the color of the frame just once. 
So, when the timer was performing comparison of the colors, he has only the initial color of the frame, so he set color of the frame to the another value, which was actually the same every time. :)

Comment: That comment would also be better as part of the answer! Good work on taking the hint and figuring out the **source** of the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the color without having to check which color is currently applied to the background:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class SwingMain {

    private static Color[] colors = {Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.PINK, Color.CYAN};
    private static int counter = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jfrmForm = new JFrame();
        jfrmForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrmForm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jfrmForm.getContentPane().setBackground(colors[counter++]);
        //add some content
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Background color chaging test");
        Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
        label.setBorder(padding);
        jfrmForm.add(label);
        jfrmForm.pack();

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, ae -> {

            jfrmForm.getContentPane().setBackground(colors[counter++]);
            if (counter >= colors.length) {
                counter = 0;
            }
        });

        timer.start();
        jfrmForm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `counter++%2` will always be 0 or 1. Well, at least until `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. At one 'tick' per second, that will be over 68 years. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nice trick, enough time to worry about it overflows :-). For random 2-state flag I also use `new Random().nextBoolean()`. In this case I want it in the range of 0 - 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of changing the background color or a Swing GUI via animation and two are demonstrated below:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class TestColorPanels extends JPanel {
    public static final int PREF_W = 400;
    public static final int PREF_H = 300;

    // constructor
    public TestColorPanels() {
        ColorTimerPanel colorTimerPanel = new ColorTimerPanel();
        ColorSliderPanel colorSliderPanel = new ColorSliderPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        add(colorTimerPanel);
        add(colorSliderPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TestColorPanels mainPanel = new TestColorPanels();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Color GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

```
class ColorTimerPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final int COLOR_COUNT = 400;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
    private static final String STOP = "Stop";
    private static final String START = "Start";
    private List<ColorHue> colorHueList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int colorIndex = 0;
    private JLabel hueValueLabel = new JLabel("000", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private Timer timer;

    public ColorTimerPanel() {
        JLabel colorHueTextLbl = new JLabel("RGB Color:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        colorHueTextLbl.setFont(colorHueTextLbl.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
        hueValueLabel.setFont(hueValueLabel.getFont().deriveFont(28f));

        Border innBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15);
        Border outBorder = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
        Border compoundBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outBorder, innBorder);

        JPanel hueValuePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        hueValuePanel.setBorder(compoundBorder);
        hueValuePanel.setOpaque(false);
        hueValuePanel.add(colorHueTextLbl, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        hueValuePanel.add(hueValueLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JToggleButton toggleButton = new JToggleButton(STOP);
        toggleButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        toggleButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        toggleButton.addItemListener(e -> timerToggled(e));

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TestColorPanels.PREF_W, TestColorPanels.PREF_H));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        add(new JLabel(), gbc); // filler
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(hueValuePanel, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(toggleButton, gbc);

        for (int i = 0; i < COLOR_COUNT; i++) {
            float hue = (float) ((i * 1.0) / COLOR_COUNT);
            String text = String.format("%03d", (int) (hue * 100));
            Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            // rgb text [r, g, b]
            String rgbText = String.format("[%03d, %03d, %03d]", color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue());
            colorHueList.add(new ColorHue(color, rgbText));
        }

        timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, e -> changeColor());
        timer.start();
    }

    private static record ColorHue(Color color, String text) {
    };

    private void changeColor() {
        setBackground(colorHueList.get(colorIndex).color);
        hueValueLabel.setText(colorHueList.get(colorIndex).text);
        colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % COLOR_COUNT;
        repaint();
    }

    private void timerToggled(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            timer.stop();
            ((AbstractButton) e.getItem()).setText(START);
        } else {
            timer.start();
            ((AbstractButton) e.getItem()).setText(STOP);
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ColorSliderPanel extends JPanel {
    private Map<ColorTitle, ColorSlider> colorSliderMap = Map.of(
        ColorTitle.RED, new ColorSlider(ColorTitle.RED, 0),
        ColorTitle.GREEN, new ColorSlider(ColorTitle.GREEN, 0),
        ColorTitle.BLUE, new ColorSlider(ColorTitle.BLUE, 0)
    );
    private Color backgroundColor = Color.BLACK;

    public ColorSliderPanel() {
        for (ColorSlider colorSlider : colorSliderMap.values()) {
            colorSlider.addPropertyChangeListener(ColorSlider.COLOR_SLIDER, e -> changeColor());
            
        }

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TestColorPanels.PREF_W, TestColorPanels.PREF_H));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 0));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));
        for (ColorTitle colorTitle : ColorTitle.values()) {
            ColorSlider colorSlider = colorSliderMap.get(colorTitle);
            add(colorSlider.getSlider());
        }
        changeColor();
    }

    private void changeColor() {
        int red = colorSliderMap.get(ColorTitle.RED).getValue();
        int green = colorSliderMap.get(ColorTitle.GREEN).getValue();
        int blue = colorSliderMap.get(ColorTitle.BLUE).getValue();
        backgroundColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        setBackground(backgroundColor);
        repaint();
    }

}
```

```
class ColorSlider {
    public static final String COLOR_SLIDER = "Color Slider";
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private ColorTitle colorTitle;
    private JSlider slider;

    public ColorSlider(ColorTitle colorTitle, int value) {
        this.colorTitle = colorTitle;
        slider = new JSlider(0, 255, value);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.setOpaque(false);
        slider.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(colorTitle.getTitle()));
        slider.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        slider.addChangeListener(e -> changeColor());
    }

    public JSlider getSlider() {
        return slider;
    }

    public void changeColor() {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(COLOR_SLIDER, null, this);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return colorTitle.getColor();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return slider.getValue();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return colorTitle.getTitle();
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        slider.setValue(value);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, java.beans.PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

}
```

```
enum ColorTitle {
    RED("Red", Color.RED), GREEN("Green", Color.GREEN), BLUE("Blue", Color.BLUE);

    private String title;
    private Color color;

    private ColorTitle(String title, Color color) {
        this.title = title;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```